# PHP socket's working correctly

Tags: php, sockets

I am attempting to make a system in which a user types in their cmd or terminal `telent {domain} {port}` of course domain would be the domain I'm using and port the port, but I'm having trouble creating the sockets, it works fine on my computer but on the VPS it just won't work. here is the code I have to create the socket.

```
<?php

echo "test";

if(!$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

?>
```

But on the page nothing appears after "test", is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set your display-errors to 1?? otherwise the exceptions aren't displayed  http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); in the top of your script

Comment: @SanderVisser I have done that now I get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\tpl\skins\HabboExtreme\socket.php on line 6` but that functions worked fine before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to your exception

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\tpl\skins\HabboExtreme\socket.php on line 6
```

The sockets extension is disabled in your php.ini

Change the following line in your php.ini

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

to the following, so that the extension is enabled don't forget to restart your IIS

```
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't have it so I just added it to the bottom, another questions, will this cause any security holes? I am also trying to allow people to do this from their computer, but it is not working, is it possible to make it work?

Comment: No security issues it just enables all related socket_* functions defined in this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: If you open up the port where you listen on your server should be accesable from the outside ;)

Comment: Yup just let your firewall allow to accept connection on port 5000 from any address

Comment: Now when I go to the url/socket page, the site goes down until I telnet it, is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: You have a VPS right? It's better to run it in your cmd  "php.exe socket.php" so it runs forever until you terminated it. you could even create a service that starts your script

Comment: I am using the php.exe method, thank you helps a lot, I plan on using to activate special privileges on users accounts if they can figure out how to do this.